# Create file inside folder without using cd to open folder

Tags: file, batch-file, directory

I'm creating a script that creates a file inside the current directory.

```
@echo off
set /p file= filename and extension: 
echo something_test >> %file%
```

But, let's say the current directory is this:

```
INSIDE (fo) main_folder: {
    (fi) script.bat
    (fo) somefolder
}
```

(fi = file and fo = folder; script.bat is the script I'm making)

If I run the script and input `file.txt`, (fi) file.txt will be created in (fi) script.bat's main directory ((fo) main_folder).

Now let's say I want to create it inside (fo) somefolder.

The obvious thing would be to do this:

```
@echo off
cd somefolder
set /p file= filename and extension: 
echo something_test >> %file%
```

Then; If I run the script and input file.txt, (fi) file.txt will be created in (fi) script.bat's WORKING directory ((fo) somefolder).

But what I want to do is to, just by inputing into the set /p command, create the file in (fo) somefolder, without using the cd command.

And how to, just by inputing into the set /p command, create the file in (fo) main_folder's main directory, without using the `cd..` command?

Comment: Using `@(Echo something_test)>>"%~dp0somefolder\%file%"` would seem too obvious to me, so perhaps there's something you haven't explained properly to us.

Comment: as obvious as `(echo something)>>"..\%file%"` for the last paragraph. So I too think the explanation is not sufficient.

Comment: @Compo and Stephan: What's there is exactly what I meant, but I'm open to further explanation, like T3RR0R did.

Comment: So did you try the single line I gave you in my comment? and if so, what happened? You can do the same using `%CD%`, `@(Echo something_test)>>"%CD%\somefolder\%file%"` or `%__CD__%`, `@(Echo something_test)>>"%__CD__%somefolder\%file%"` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Main Script, prior to calling any functions, Use:

```
Set "Prog_Dir=%~dp0"

REM %~dp0 Expands to the directory which the Batch is run in - The folder it's in.

Set "somefolder=%Prog_Dir%somefolder"
```

To create a file In your Scripts Dir:

```
(
ECHO Your text
) >"%Prog_Dir%\filename.ext"
```

To create a file In your Scripts Sub Dir:

```
(
ECHO Your text
) >"%somefolder%\filename.ext"
```

This approach of using relative pathways ensures the script will function as intended irregardless of where the scripts folder is located.

In order to use set /p to adjust the directory, use it to test a value.
EG:

```
Set \p StoreLocation=[1: MainDirectory 2:SomeFolder]
IF %StoreLocation%==1 Set "SaveLoc=%Prog_Dir%"

IF %StoreLocation%==2 Set "SaveLoc=%somefolder%\"
```

And change your store method to:

```
(
ECHO Your text
) >"%SaveLoc%filename.ext"
```

I would however recommend using choice within a callable function to change the value over using set /p.